# Adding a new contact to the address book through my Android app targeting Android 2.1+

Tags: android-contacts, android-2.1-eclair

When my app wants to add a new contact to the device's address book, I'd like a dialog to pop up that asks the user whether the app can add "Some Contact" to their address book, and I'd like that whole process to be facilitated by the OS. That is, I don't want to add a `permission` to `WRITE_CONTACTS`. How do I request Android to attempt to add a contact to the address book without having to add that permission to my manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  If you don't add the WRITE_CONTACTS permission, your app can't write to the contacts.